# CSS and Images on windows azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, bundle

[image]The project is done on MVC5, and when i publish the project through visual studio on azure, the images and css effects cannot be done. I did try through the Bundling.config but still cannot get it done. i have an img folder inside Content (it has all the images).

I have the following in my bundle config file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/img").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/base.css",
                      "~/Content/parallaxstyle.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                     "~/Content/pricing.css",
                     "~/Content/pricing2.css"));
```

and in view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/img")
```

But it doesn't even render the css files.

This is the root.
The layout view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/img/demo/_small")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/base.css")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you created a `StyleBundle`, and are trying to render a `ScriptBundle`.

Change this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/img")
```

To this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/img")
```

Note that if you have an actual folder at `~/Content/img`, consider changing the name of the bundle so that there is no name clash.

Comment: I did change it to Styles.Render, but it didn't work as well. Here is my site. http://pcrux.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Which bit isn't working?  It looks like those CSS files are being loaded.  If you have a "Content/img" folder in your site, then you need to rename the bundle.

Comment: I can;t get the images. Also for other tabs, like OverView, can't see the CSS effects.

Comment: Please read the entire comment.  I suspect you have an "img" subfolder in your "Content" folder.  Change the name of your bundle so that there is no name clash.  eg. "~/Content/sitestyle"

Comment: That didn't help either. Cannot get the images, and CSS effects for other pages. What I have is Content, and the css files are in there. Inside the content theres an image folder, and other sub folders.

Comment: Please post the layout view that you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63898/discussion-between-brendan-green-and-sooner).